# How to get mouse and keyboard moves? - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, keyboard, mouse

I am looking for a way to achieve these goals. Please read them and if you know of a way that can get me (directly or indirectly) to even some of these goals. Do not hesitate please.

- get pressed key.

  - It is better to be in the shape of an aunt
    for example:

  ```py
  ... # defund or import

  @event # for all of keys
  def on_key_press(key):
     ...

  @event # for ctrl key (for example)
  def on_ctrl_press(key):
     ...
  ```
- Press a key
  like this:

```py
press('ctrl')
```

- and do the same for pc mouse

Comment: You haven't asked any questions!

Comment: How to get mouse and keyboard gestures?

Comment: What does "_I can understand what key has been pressed._" , "_I can press a key with it using a code like this_" and "_and do the same for pc mouse_" mean?

Comment: I think he means that a function is called where one parameter will be the key(sym) and he wants to be able to press a key with using a function. Refer to my answer for better explanation what i think he wants to achieve.

Comment: @sputnick567 he may want to say that but we have to understand him according to his question right? He told that he knows everything things to do and he also provides the code to do that then what is he asking for? And title is not the place to ask questions, title is to describe question in short form, please read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit!

Comment: @Delta please edit your question! Title is not the place to ask questions, title is to describe question in short form,  please read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question!

Comment: @Kshitiz: Basically the OP is asking for a software recommendation in a sneaky way (because an earlier question where they asked more directly was closed, because that's off-topic here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `pynput` (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) should solve your problem. It allows you to press buttons on keyboard and mouse as well as get when a button is pressed. You may need to perform `pip install pynput`